# Combine 2 Case Queries and return a 1 Or 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have 2 validation queries I use in 2 seperate functions in vb.net. These 2 functions are called for every order_num that is processed through my application. I would like to combine the two case queries into one with one result value of either a 1 or 0. Thanks in advance.

First Query:

```
select case when EXISTS (
select 1
    from [Sonora].[dbo].[tbl_Informatics_Orders_Data] with (nolock)
    where segment IN ('PID','ZPI', 'ZRQ', 'ZSI') AND order_num = '780630021555'
) then 1 else 0 end as [SegmentsExist]
```

Second Query:

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN
(SELECT COUNT(*) As result_count FROM [Sonora].[dbo].[tbl_Informatics_Orders_Data] 
with (nolock) WHERE segment = 'OBR' AND order_num = '780630021555') 
= 
(SELECT COUNT(*) As result_count FROM [Sonora].[dbo].[tbl_Informatics_Orders_Data] 
with (nolock)   WHERE segment = 'OBX' AND order_num = '780630021555')
THEN 1
ELSE 0
End AS returnValue
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are having? What do you have so far?

Comment: I am trying to limit the amount of function calls to the server. These 2 queries are run for every order. Order counts are between 30-40 thousand. I am trying to increase the speed of this process.

Comment: Yes but what have you tried so far? Do you have a query where you've tried to combine the two? What is it that you're struggling with?

Comment: Im really looking for a place to start. I have looked at examples for case statements, but i'm having trouble finding examples of 2 sets of criteria with 1 where clause.

Comment: What is the logic for combining them?  Both "1" or either "1"?

Comment: Both need to be 1 in order for the order to be valid. If either one is 0 then the order is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the bigger issue you'll have is your program structure. You mention that these queries (or 1 query) will be run against 30k-40k orders. That's a ridiculous amount of times to run a single query, especially when you could be running this in a set based fashion.

I would advise refactoring your queries to run for the entire dataset, store the results as a dataset in VB, then do what you will from there. You're never going to get good performance if you're running a seek/scan based operation for every single row in a database as opposed to returning a dataset.

EDIT: A little more about datasets.

When you're running queries for a single result (`WHERE order_num = '780630021555'`), the database has to look at every single row in the table to make sure it finds all records where order_num = '780630021555'. Now, you say there are 40k records.. which means for every single one of those 40,000 updates, the database must look at every single record of the table. Scanning a 40,000 row table 40,000 times adds up to about 1.6 billion rows being read. SQL will try to optimize and may scan the table less, but this is essentially what you're doing.

The ideal way to do it is to return data for the entire table. Write your query to return a 1 or 0 for ALL the order numbers, then do your processing from there. This way, the 40k rows of the table are only read once. Something like this:

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN (segment IN ('PID','ZPI', 'ZRQ', 'ZSI') OR OBR_Count = OBX_Count) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Valid_Record
FROM [Sonora].[dbo].[tbl_Informatics_Orders_Data] IOD with (nolock)
JOIN
(
    SELECT order_num, COUNT(segment) OBR_Count
    FROM [Sonora].[dbo].[tbl_Informatics_Orders_Data] with (nolock)
    WHERE segment = 'OBR'
    GROUP BY order_num
) OBR
ON IOD.order_num = OBR.order_num
JOIN
(
    SELECT order_num, COUNT(segment) OBX_Count
    FROM [Sonora].[dbo].[tbl_Informatics_Orders_Data] with (nolock)
    WHERE segment = 'OBX'
    GROUP BY order_num
) OBX
ON IOD.order_num = OBX.order_num
```

This should return a row for every single order number in your table. It will return it with a Valid_Record column, indicating whether the criteria you specified is true (a 1) or it is not (a 0). I haven't run  this query but it looks right. It will take a while to run, maybe a minute, but I can guarantee the operation you're doing selecting every single result individually is taking many times longer.

I work with several tables in SQL Server that have over a billion rows on a daily basis. In those cases, very small changes in queries make a big difference in query times. In tables that have 40k rows max, you will get much more performance out of refactoring the query to give you a dataset instead of giving you single results 40k times.

Comment: I am not familiar with set based fashion, what do you mean?

Comment: This application is creating the segment data and inserting into the table. I run the evaluation on the newly created data to determine if it meets the correct criteria. An order includes a set of multiple segments that cannot be evaluated individually but as a whole.

Comment: Understood. I do not know all the specifics so you will have to make the final call as to what is best in your situation. With data, it is best to think in terms of data sets, doing lots of things to large groups of data, instead of doing one thing to one row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If the logic is "or", you can do:

```
select (case when EXISTS (select 1
                          from [Sonora].[dbo].[tbl_Informatics_Orders_Data] with (nolock)
                          where segment IN ('PID','ZPI', 'ZRQ', 'ZSI') AND
                                order_num = '780630021555'
                         )
             then 1
             when (SELECT COUNT(*) As result_count
                   FROM [Sonora].[dbo][tbl_Informatics_Orders_Data] with (nolock)
                   WHERE segment = 'OBR' AND order_num = '780630021555') =
                  (SELECT COUNT(*) As result_count
                   FROM [Sonora].[dbo].[tbl_Informatics_Orders_Data] with (nolock)
                   WHERE segment = 'OBX' AND order_num = '780630021555'
                  )
             then 1
             else 0
        end) as [SegmentsExist];
```

If the logic is "and":

```
select (case when EXISTS (select 1
                          from [Sonora].[dbo].[tbl_Informatics_Orders_Data] with (nolock)
                          where segment IN ('PID','ZPI', 'ZRQ', 'ZSI') AND
                                order_num = '780630021555'
                         ) and
                  (SELECT COUNT(*) As result_count
                   FROM [Sonora].[dbo][tbl_Informatics_Orders_Data] with (nolock)
                   WHERE segment = 'OBR' AND order_num = '780630021555') =
                  (SELECT COUNT(*) As result_count
                   FROM [Sonora].[dbo].[tbl_Informatics_Orders_Data] with (nolock)
                   WHERE segment = 'OBX' AND order_num = '780630021555'
                  )
             then 1
             else 0
        end) as [SegmentsExist];
```

EDIT:

You can simplify the second condition to directly return `1` or `0`:

```
                  (SELECT (case when sum(case when segment = 'OBR' then 1 else 0 end) =
                                     sum(case when segment = 'OBX' then 1 else 0 end)
                                then 1 else 0
                           end)
                   FROM [Sonora].[dbo][tbl_Informatics_Orders_Data] with (nolock)
                   WHERE segment IN ('OBR', 'OBX') AND order_num = '780630021555'
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get the order_num from? If it's based on a query againste the very same database I'd rather go for a totally different approach and let SQL Server perform the evaluation in a set based fashion rather than trying to speed up the function call and still call it a few thousand times...

Comment: the order_num is passed from an array to the function.